# CiviCRM in a NEOS website

Tags: cms-integration, integration

Hi I have a Website with NEOS CMS. is it possible to implement CiviCRM Events, Payments etc. in that Website?

Answer (score 2):

I take it you have already read that CiviCRM is designed to work with only the following 4 CMS: Drupal, WordPress, Joomla and Backdrop.

Therefore I assume you are asking a question more along the lines of 'how can I embed a form for event registrations on a standalone CMS?'

There are tools (RemoteForm, CMRF) that allow for this but they still all require CiviCRM to be set up with D, WP, J or B but will then capture the data from a from on an external website. Suggest you read

[How can I connect my website to CiviCRM on a remote server?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35904/how-can-i-connect-my-website-to-civicrm-on-a-remote-server)

https://civicrm.org/blog/jamie/display-civicrm-forms-on-any-web-site-anywhere

Comment: D, WP, J and Backdrop!

Comment: Thx Aidan. updated the Answer