# Integration with the Webflow platform

Tags: cms-integration

I have experience with CiviCRM and am considering it for a new client. They have multiple websites and constituent databases. Their primary website is built on Weblow with a Shopify subdomain. Will CiviCRM play nice with Webflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CiviCRM doesn't integrate directly with Webflow. As Demerit has said it only integrates directly with WordPress, Drupal, Joomla and Backdrop.

However, this isn't necessarily a problem. There are many organisations that host their CRM separately from the main website. Any integration can be performed via the API and/or with the help of some of these extensions:

- [Inlay](https://docs.civicrm.org/inlay/en/latest/)
- [Form Processor](https://docs.civicrm.org/formprocessor/en/latest/)
- [CiviProxy](https://docs.civicrm.org/civiproxy/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1):

You can only install it with the cms's listed at https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest.

Depending on what you need, you don't have to really do anything with that cms except set up users in it, and then you could use one of a couple remote options to connect data. See e.g. [How can I connect my website to CiviCRM on a remote server?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35904/how-can-i-connect-my-website-to-civicrm-on-a-remote-server)

Not sure if you need to integrate with shopify at all but see also https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/shopify

Comment: Also there is work being done for a 'standalone' CiviCRM but not really production ready afaik